# How to add last name to page number in header?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

Okay so I am writing a report where in the header, my teacher is requiring that I put both the page number and my last name in the upper-left hand corner of each page (excluding the title page). Now I have managed to put the page number in the upper-left hand corner using

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
```

but this doesn't solve my issue of putting my last name right next to the page number. Help?

Comment: Try out the fancyhdr package.  You may also find these examples and explanations helpful.  https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Headers_and_footers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation of the `fancyhdr` package will be extremely helpful to you.  Essentially, you need to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \lhead{Yourname, \thepage}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Since your title page is the only one that's different, you can just say `\thispagestyle{empty}` on your title page, and you'll get no headers or footers.

If `fancyhdr`'s default of a header rule bothers you, put in `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to kill it.

Comment: Sorry one more thing to add. So I added the fancyhdr to my doc, but there is an underlining below that takes up the top of the page. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: With `\fancyfoot{}` nothing goes in those brackets. unless you want to put something there. If you don't want anything there, they should be left blank. If you want something in your footer, you put it in there. `\thepage` is a macro. You don't put in the page number, no, LaTeX will print whatever the correct page number is. The function of `\lipsum` is provided by the `lipsum` package and it prints the text of lorem ipsum (google it if you're unfamiliar). You can see that our original poster includes the appropriate `pagestyle` in their example. `\pagestyle{fancy}`

Comment: The rule in the header is also in the `fancyhdr` documentation.  Something like `\setlength{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` should do it, but confirm that in the manual.  I'm away from my desktop at the moment.  `texdoc fancyhdr`.

Comment: That didn't work. when I added that command, it just added "0.4pt0pt" to my text for some weird reason.

Comment: The macro `\headrulewidth` needs to be reset via a `\renewcommand` instruction. E.g., `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`.

Comment: Thanks for filling that in, Mico.  Though I'm not quite sure what's so frightening about looking at the documentation.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii -- you might add the information about getting rid of the head rule to your answer.  that way it will be easier for a future user to notice it.

Comment: Good idea; will do.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is using [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage). I guess that your document is `oneside`:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\ihead*{Yourname, \pagemark}
```

With the `article` class you have to use `\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}` to get an empty title page.

Oneside `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\ihead*{Yourname, \pagemark}

\author{Yourname}
\title{Title}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Oneside `report`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\ihead*{Yourname, \pagemark}

\author{Yourname}
\title{Title}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note, that the header appears also an chapter pages. To remove the header from the chapter pages simple use `\ihead{...}` instead `\ihead*{...}`.

---

If your document is `twoside` an the header should be an the left hand side on both the even and the odd pages than you have to use

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\lehead*{Yourname, \pagemark}
\lohead*{Yourname, \pagemark}
```

Twoside `report`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\lehead*{Yourname, \pagemark}
\lohead*{Yourname, \pagemark}

\author{Yourname}
\title{Title}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```